# Dereferencing a pointer to a struct to access its first member

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dereference

For specific reasons i want to access only the first member of a struct by dereferencing the pointer to the struct.

I would like to know if is this legal or can it cause UB under some conditions; and what would be a correct solution, if this one has any problems.

Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct test_s
{
    void * data ;
    struct test_s * next ;

} test_t ;


int main( void )
{
    test_t * t = calloc( 1 , sizeof( test_t ) ) ;

    int n = 123;

    t->data = &n ; //int is used only for an address, this could be anything, an object for example
    void ** v = ( void* )t ;
    printf("Address of  n: %p\nAddress of *t: %p\n\n" , &n , *v ) ; //dereference the pointer to struct to access its first member

return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not just use void **v = &t->data ?

Comment: @giorashc identification of t is lost in my code, all i have is a void pointer to t. Above is just an example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is legal. From C99, 6.7.2.1.13:

> A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is 100% legal: C standard specifies that the pointer to a `struct` must always equal to the pointer to the initial member of that `struct`.

Comment: If pointer to struct `ps = &struct` has address of the first member of that struct `struct.member`, then why is needed to dereference the pointer `ps` in order to access that first member? Because If the `ps` holds the address of first member as you suggested, then I would simple acces that member by `ps.member` and not `ps->member`? This should be possible if `ps==&struct.firstmember`

Comment: @Herdsman I do not suggest anything, I state exactly what the standard says.

Comment: The question was only meant for explanation, I know how it works, but do not just get the need of `->` to access `first member` in struct, when both (struct pointer, first member pointer) have the same address. Why cannot I simply do `ps.firstmember` (with dot, not with arrow), when the address is the same

Comment: @Herdsman Dot `.` and arrow `->` operators are completely interconvertible in C language: you can replace all uses of `s.f` with `&s->f`, and all uses of `p->f` with `(*p).f`. In fact, when I taught myself C from the K&R book some 33 years ago, I missed `->` operator on the first reading, and coded everything using the dot operator `.` even when I had to dereference a pointer. I was lucky enough to have a mentor who pointed out this issue to me.

Comment: That is the how to use it. but if I have `struct foo { int first;int second; }; ` then even the initialization of `struct foo mystruct` is pointer (or what is a value of foo, if not address)? because how other would I access the `second` member? I need to take offset from the first one with 2*4 bytes to get to the second? Then even the `.` is dereference, because by `foo.second` I dereference the address from beginning (first member) to get to the second member by the offset. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Herdsman When I say that addresses are the same, I don't mean that pointers are the same, because pointers of the same value but different type have different behavior. Knowing that your pointer is of type `struct foo* pfoo` C compiler takes care of figuring out offsets for you. When you write `pfoo->first`, the compiler knows not to add anything to the pointer before dereferencing. When you write `pfoo->second`, the compiler knows to add `sizeof(int)` to the raw value.

Comment: but what actually is dereference value of `(*fpo).anything`.Dereferenced `pfoo` should contain only address, address to the first member? What is otherwise value of `struct foo` by itself? Because when you write `pfoo->first`, `pfoo` gets first dereferenced, but to what? How is it different then `pfoo.first` when both operator `.` `->` are accessing an address depending on the offset of accessing member. As I understand types, ex. `int a = 5`, it has value `5` stored in 4 bytes. But what is stored in `struct foo`? An address. That is the question between `.` and `->`, when both do the same

Comment: And by pointer  behaviour, I unfortunately know only one (or learnt) just pointer arithmetic. I do not what specifically you mean by `because pointers of the same value but different type have different behavior`. I would guess because of types and their byte-size, but how specifically they behave I do not know. From what you said, I though the differences by the pointers and their types is the different pointers can 'see` where the type begin and end (bounds), e.g. int* knows to look, whether 4 consecutive bytes have a value. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Herdsman Exactly. `int*` knows that you can pull an `int` from it without adding any offset, while from `struct foo*` it could pull an `int` at offset of zero when you ask for `first`, and another `int` at offset of `sizeof(int)` when you ask for `second`.

Comment: So what is the value of `struct foo` by itself? What value I can obtaion from dereferencing a pointer to that struct (e.g. (*foo))